# Nil and concatenation behaviour (nil && nil + "string")

Tags: ruby

I noticed some behaviour of the `&&` operator in combination with string concatenation.

```
nil + "string"
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

a = (nil && nil)
# => nil
a + "string"
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

nil && nil + "string"
# => nil
```

Can someone explain it?

Comment: Evaluation of `x_1 && x_2 && ... && x_n` stops as soon as the first `x_i` that evaluates to `false` or `nil` is found. Thus, in `nil && nil + "string"` it will never evaluate `nil + "string"`. If you do `true && nil + "string"` you get the same error as you would expect.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Due to higher precedence, `nil && nil + "string"`, is actually `nil && (nil + "string")`, which causes, the left side exp not to evaluate in this example.. I believe.

Comment: @Arup Yeah I know, I thought that was obvious. But perhaps OP indeed thought it was `(nil && nil) + "string"`. In that case I can understand the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just [operator precedence](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence).

```
nil && nil + "string"
```

is the same as

```
nil && (nil + "string")
```

because `+` has higher precedence.  Since `&&` returns the left operand if its `nil` or `false` and then short-circuits (doesn't bother computing the right operand), you never see the `NoMethodError` that would result from evaluating `nil + "string"`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `&&` short-circuits. (`A && B` evaluates `B` only if `A` is truth value)

`nil` is a falsy value.; `nil + "string"` in `nil && nil + "string"` is not evaluated.

(`nil && nil + "string"` is equivalent to `nil && (nil + "string")` because [`&&` has lower precedence than `+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html))

Comment: ... sometimes referred to as "lazy evaluation".

Comment: nope, it's not about `&&` short-circuit but operators precedence order like Amit answered (`+` is higher)

Comment: @DavidUnric It is not **only** about short-circuit, but short-circuit is crucial. Otherwise, the examples without errors would raise an error. You need to mention short-circuit in order to explain the contrast.

Comment: @sawa first thing is the operator precedence or the expression would result in exception. you are correct then applies the short-circuit of `&&` so the right side won't get evaled.

Comment: @DavidUnric, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer to explicitly mention the operator precedence.